# Comparing uint8_t data with string

Tags: c++, wav

This may sounds little odd or question may be a trivial one, but for most of my life I was programming in PHP (yeah, I know how it sounds). So when I switched to C++ there are things quite unfamilliar for me (cause of php habits).

So I'm loading wav header data using struct. Values are definded as uint8_t type:

```
typedef struct  WAV_HEADER
{
   uint8_t         RIFF[4];        // RIFF
   uint8_t         WAVE[4];        // WAVE
}
```

I have to compare them with four-letter strings for something like that:

```
if(wavHeader.RIFF[0] . wavHeader.RIFF[1] . wavHeader.RIFF[2] . wavHeader.RIFF[3] == 'RIFF')
{ do sth }
```

This should be easy check if loaded file is a Wave file (*.wav). Thanks for any help.

Comment: What you probably want is `if(memcmp(wavHeader.RIFF,"RIFF",4) == 0)`

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thank you. By the way, is there any other resolution, that includes not including memory.h?

Comment: Of course you can also do `if(wavHeader.RIFF[0] == 'R' && wavHeader.RIFF[1]  == 'I' && wavHeader.RIFF[2]  == 'F' && wavHeader.RIFF[3] == 'F')`

Comment: non-portable solution, needs `RIFF` to be properly aligned: `*(int*)RIFF == 'RIFF'` or `*(int*)RIFF == 'FFIR'` depending on endianness. To make it more portable: `*(int*)RIFF == 0x46464952`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in C and C++ are [null-terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037209/what-is-a-null-terminated-string). `RIFF` and `WAVE` aren't technically C-style strings because there is no null terminator, so you can't just use a straightforward C/C++-style string compare like `strcmp`. There are however several ways you could compare them against the strings you want:

- `if (header.RIFF[0] == 'R' &&
       header.RIFF[1] == 'I' &&
       header.RIFF[2] == 'F' &&
       header.RIFF[3] == 'F') { // .. }`
- `if (strncmp((const char*)header.RIFF, "RIFF", 4) == 0) { // .. }`
- `if (memcmp(header.RIFF, "RIFF", 4) == 0) { // .. }`

I would personally use either `strncmp` or `memcmp`. They end up doing the same thing, but semantically `strncmp` is a string compare function which maybe makes the code clearer.

For `strncmp` see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/).
For `memcmp` see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/).

Comment: What error do you get, and what compiler are you using? You'll have to include `string.h` to use `strncmp`.

Comment: Oops, thanks, I updated my answer. You'll have to cast the `RIFF` member to a `const char*` to use `strncmp`.

Comment: I just meant that they aren't technically strings since they don't have any null terminator, but semantically you would probably think of them as strings. I added some text to mention that. Hopefully it's a bit clearer.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say that makes your logic a lot clearer, thanks.