# Dereferencing array pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I'm trying to dereference this pointer to a new array (ARR) , but from this example below when i do the derefencing `*issub` it only "carries" the first letter. How can i fix this situation and have `ARR(subscount)` be the word i want?

```
#include <iostream>
  int main(){
  char inp[3]={'O','I','L'};
  int lll=3;
  char ARR[3];
  int subscount=0;

  char * issub= new char[lll];
  for(int i=0;i<lll;i++){
    issub[i]=inp[i];
  }
  ARR[subscount]=*issub;
 }
```

Comment: Your code is bad because inp is being accessed with out-of-bounds index!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Fill every cell of `ARR` so it will be the same with `inp`, **or** have a pointer in `ARR[subscount]` will will point to the word?

Comment: @gsamaras i want `ARR[0]` to be "OIL" just like inp

Comment: But @J.Barbosa `inp[0]` is 'O', not "OIL".

Comment: @gsamaras But if i print issub before the ARR it prints the whole word

Comment: Yes exactly @J.Barbosa, I will post an answer.

Comment: Dynamic arrays are a very odd language feature. This is the only time that an object exists whose type is not the type of any expression in the language. You could reinterpret cast to `char(*)[111]` if you wanted to, but that's really fighting the language (and doesn't work if you have  dynamic size).

Comment: How are you "print issub" ?

Comment: @ M.M if you do `std::cout<< issub<<std::endl;` right after the for cycle it prints the word

Comment: Are you looking for some way to copy a string? If so, `strcpy` is what you want.

Comment: @J.Barbosa that causes undefined behaviour; there is no null termination on `issub`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `strcpy` does not work on char arrays that do not contain strings (as in this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that you are confused, so I made an example for you:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  char inp[4] = {'O','I','L', '\0'};
  int lll = 4;
  // initialize elements of 'ARR' to 0 for safety
  char ARR[4] = {0};
  int subscount = 0;

  // dynamic allocation, DO NOT forget to de-allocate
  char* issub = new char[lll];
  // copy every element of 'inp' to 'issub'
  for(int i=0;i<lll;i++) {
    issub[i]=inp[i];
  }
  // this will copy where '*issub' points to,
  // that is the 'issub[0]', to 'ARR[subscount]'
  ARR[subscount] = *issub;
  std::cout << ARR << "\n"; // prints: O
  // you can use a for loop as before to copy the contents,
  // from 'inp', 'issub' to 'ARR'

  // However, we will do something different here,
  // so I am de-allocating 'issub'
  delete [] issub;

  // We will use an array of pointers, with size 2,
  // thus it will have two pointers in total.
  char* ptr_arr[2];

  // Assign the first pointer to 'inp'
  ptr_arr[0] = &(inp[0]);

  std::cout << ptr_arr[0] << "\n"; // prints OIL

  // we don't use the second pointer,
  // set it to NULL
  ptr_arr[1] = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps (but it really reminds me of C, rather than C++, where [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) should be used).

---

Updated with a null terminated string; [What is a null-terminated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037209/what-is-a-null-terminated-string)

<sub>Thanks @M.M</sub>

Comment: I think i got it down,but shouldn't `inp[0]` be just the first character?

Comment: @J.Barbosa `inp[0]` is the first character. Yes.