# Storing data in char array causing corruption around variable

Tags: c++

I am working on a C++ project and I am having an issue.

Below is my code

```
tempfingerprint = libssh2_hostkey_hash(session, LIBSSH2_HOSTKEY_TYPE_RSA);
    char temp[48];
    memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        //fingerprintstream << (unsigned char)tempfingerprint[i] << ":";
        if (temp[0] == 0)
        {
            sprintf(temp, "%02X:", (unsigned char)tempfingerprint[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            //sprintf(temp, "%s:%02X", temp, (unsigned char)tempfingerprint[i]);
            char characters[3];
            memset(characters, 0, sizeof(characters));
            //If less than 16, then add the colon (:) to the end otherwise don't bother as we're at the end of the fingerprint
            sprintf(characters, "%02X:", (unsigned char)tempfingerprint[i]);
            strcat(temp, characters);
        }
    }
    //Remove the end colon as its not needed. 48 Will already be null terminated, so the previous will contain the last colon
    temp[47] = 0;
    return string(temp);
```

When I run my app, I get the following error from visual studio

```
Run-Time-Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'temp' was corrupted.
```

I've ran the same code on Linux through Valgrind and no errors were shown so I'm not sure what the problem is with Windows.

Comment: *I've ran the same code on Linux through Valgrind and no errors were shown so I'm not sure what the problem is with Windows.* -- It isn't a problem with Windows.  Why are you using character arrays, and hoping that they're large enough to hold the data you're placing in them?   Looks like you're writing `C` and not `C++`.

Comment: `characters` looks too short.

Comment: Wouldn't `"%02X:"` produce more than 3 characters, if you count the terminating nul character.

Comment: Why would it be more, an int converted to unsigned char, i.e. int 99 will be converted to unsigned char in a hex value padded to 2 characters with a `:` on the end, e.g. 97:

Comment: @Boardy -- Why are you micromanaging the size of the array like that?  If you're off by a single byte, you have a buffer overrun in the sprintf call.  That entire routine could have been written using `std::string` without introducing any character arrays.

Comment: `characters`  will contain "97:\0", 4 characters. The '\0' on the end is the null terminator marking the end of the string. More here: [What is a null-terminated string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037209/what-is-a-null-terminated-string)

Comment: Why would it have \0 on the end. I tried adding 4 characters to the array size just in case but still get the same error

Comment: @Boardy -- *I tried adding 4 characters to the array size just in case but still get the same error* -- "Just in case"... Change to using `std::string` and `std::ostringstream`, and there isn't a need for "just in case", as the string will grow as you add characters to it.

Comment: I did try using that originally, but didn't work, this way seemed a lot easier to use/understand. It was something about using stringstream (I assume is the same ostringstream) with hex conversion but it would end up printing rubbish

Comment: C-style character strings have an implicit NUL character at the end. So, `"97:"` is the four character, `'9'`, `'7'`, `':'` and `'\000'`. Similarly, `temp` has, at one point, 49 characters. If you aren't going to use `std::string`, try `char characters[4];` and `char temp[49];`.

Comment: @Boardy *I did try using that originally, but didn't work,* -- Probably you needed to post that as the original question then to start using character arrays and introduce buffer overruns.  What is `tempfingerprint` declared as, and what would be a sample of what it contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using on what Paul McKenzie's talking about (though he might implement it differently) based on it looks like you were trying to do with the stream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip> // output format modifiers
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream fingerprintstream;
    // set up the stream to print uppercase hex with 0 padding if required
    fingerprintstream << hex << uppercase << setfill('0');

    // print out the first value without a ':'
    fingerprintstream << setw(2) << 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) // starting at 1 because first has already been handled.
    {
        // print out the rest prepending the ':'
        fingerprintstream << ":" << setw(2) << i;
    }
    // print results
    std::cout << fingerprintstream.str();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00:01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:0A:0B:0C:0D:0E:0F
```

Just realized what I think OP ran up against with the garbage output. When you output a number, `<<` will use the appropriate conversion to get text, but if you output a character `<<` prints the character. So `fingerprintstream << (unsigned char)tempfingerprint[i];` takes the binary value at `tempfingerprint[i]` and, thanks to the cast, tries to render it as a character.  Rather than "97", you will get (assuming ASCII) "a". A large amount of what you try to print will give nonsense characters.

Example: If I change

```
fingerprintstream << ":" << setw(2) << i;
```

to

```
fingerprintstream << ":" << setw(2) << (unsigned char)i;
```

the output becomes

```
0?:0?:0?:0?:0?:0?:0?:0?:0?:0?:0 :0
:0?:0?:0
:0?:0?
```

Note the tab and the line feeds.

I need to know the definition of `tempfingerprint` to be sure, but you can probably solve the garbage output problem by removing the cast.

Based on new information, `tempfingerprint` is `const char *`, so `tempfingerprint[i]` is a `char` and will be printed as a character.

We want a number, so we have to force the sucker to be an integer.

```
static_cast<unsigned int>(tempfingerprint[i]&0xFF)
```

the `&0xFF` masks out everything but the last byte, eliminating sign extension of negative numbers into huge positive numbers when displayed unsigned.

Comment: Thanks, tempfingerprint is a `const char *`. I tried removing the cast so it was just `fingerprintstream << std::setw(2) << tempfingerprint[i];`but I still get gibberish

Comment: @Boardy Give us a sample of `fingerprintstream` data, as "gibberish" doesn't convey any information.

Comment: The gibberish is `00e0~0
0®0x0/0┌0ý0h0ñ0` I'm expecting `11:65:7E:0A:94:55:88:77:EC:68:A4:0D:A9` as an example (I've truncated the full output I'm expecting). The output isn't quite the same, as it has some special characters as well so I can post a screenshot instead if you wish

Comment: If `tempfingerprint` is `const char *` then `tempfingerprint[i]` is a `char` and we have to force the sucker to be an integer. `(unsigned int) (tempfingerprint[i]&0xFF)` the `&0xFF` masks out everything but the last byte, eliminating sign extension.

Comment: Ah that's done it, I don't really understand though what's the `&0xFF` is everything, quite new to C++ so haven't fully got to grips with everything yet.

Comment: `&0xFF` is a binary AND with one byte's worth of 1s. example: 128 (0x80 as a character is a negative number. It will extend to 0xFFFFFF80 if converted to an `int`. We don't want the extra nonsense, so we mask it out 0xFFFFFF80 AND 0x000000FF = 0x80.

Comment: This shenanigans is necessary because `libssh2_hostkey_hash` is badly designed, it should not return pointer to signed characters when the data is unsigned

Comment: What do you think of something like `static_cast<unsigned int>( static_cast<unsigned char>(x) )`? While it's ugly, maybe can better express the intention.

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes sense, I tried converting to `unsigned` from another example on SO before your comment, and I was wondering why I was getting something `FFFFF11:FFFFFF65:`

Comment: @Bob__ I gave that double cast some thought, but went back to the old school approach out of fear of  `char`s of unusual size. Damn things pop up when you least expect them. That said, I should have used the C++ style casts in the answer. Will fix when I get time and remember.

Answer (score 0):

There are, as far as I see, two issues in the code which lead to exceeding array boundaries:

First, with `char temp[48]` you reserve exactly 48 characters for storing results; However, when calling `strcat(temp, characters)` with the 16th value, and `characters` comprises at least the characters including the colon, then temp will comprise 16*3 digits/colons + one terminating `'\0'`-character, i.e. 49 characters (not 48). Note that `strcat` automatically appends a string terminating char.

Second, you define `char characters[3]` such that you reserve place for two digits and the colon, but not for the terminating  `'\0'`-character. Hence, an `sprintf(characters, "%02X:",...)` will exceed `characters`s array bounds, as `sprintf` also appends the string terminator.

So, if you do not want to rewrite your code in general, changing your definitions to `char temp[49]` and `char characters[4]` will solve the problem.