# i came across this code snippet and do not understand. it recursively checks if an upper case char is present in a c++ string

Tags: c++, string, recursion

the base checks for null character but aren't c++ strings not supposed to be null terminated? should the base case check for length of the string?

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

// Function to find string which has 
// first character of each word. 
char first(string str, int i=0) 
{ 
    if (str[i] == '\0') 
         return 0; 
    if (isupper(str[i]))  
            return str[i]; 
    return first(str, i+1); 
} 

// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    string str = "geeksforGeeKS"; 
    char res = first(str); 
    if (res == 0) 
        cout << "No uppercase letter"; 
    else
        cout << res << "\n"; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Standard guarantees, since C++11 (at least) that it is null terminated.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2037215/10686048

Comment: @ChrisMM and even before C++11, most implementations were null terminated to simply the implementation of `c_str()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau But for example, in libstdc++ it wasn't. It was fairly widely used implementation even back then as far as I know.

Comment: 1. if you do this, use iterators. 2. if you ignore (1), use a const reference; stop needlessly making copies of strings.

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: @WhozCraig oh ok thanku!

Comment: @Lightness Races BY-SA 3.0 thanku!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> aren't c++ strings not supposed to be null terminated

`std::string` are (guaranteed to be) null terminated (since C++11).

> should the base case check for length of the string?

It could be. But it doesn't need to be, because of the null termination.

Answer (score 2):

> aren't c++ strings not supposed to be null terminated?

Since C++11, `std::string` is guaranteed to be null-terminated.

---

> should the base case check for length of the string?

Yes, if you want to handle strings that contain null characters.

For instance,

```
string str("ab\0cD", 5);
```

Comment: It should be done that way anyway, because that is the interface of the type. The code in the question clearly originates from an old C implementation. Yes, `std::string` is null terminated due to an abstraction leak that had to be baked into the standard, but I wouldn't accept at code review any code that iterated a `std::string` as does that in the question.