# Weird symbols in copied/truncated character array

Tags: c++, c-strings

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void truncate(char* s1, char* s2, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s2[i] = s1[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    char s1[15] = "Hello World";
    char s2[10];
    int n{ 5 };
    truncate(s1, s2, n);
    cout << s2; // this should display: Hello
}
```

When I run this in Visual Studio, I get this output:

```
Hello╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠Hello World
```

But when I run it using an online compiler (Online GDB), the output is normal:

```
Hello
```

I know it has to do with the `\0` terminator but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Don't forget that C-style strings are _null terminated_.

Comment: Note: The main function was provided as it is in the post above by my teacher, so I can't change the arrays sizes'.

Comment: And in fact you don't need to change the array sizes. But do make sure that `s2` ends with a null character at the end of the `truncate()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `truncate` function doesn't add the **required** [`nul` terminator character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2037209/10871073) to the destination (`s2`) string. Thus, when you call `cout` in `main`, that will keep printing characters until it finds its expected `nul` (zero) character at some unspecified location following the garbage-initialized data that pre-exists in the parts of the `s2` local array that weren't explicitly set by your function. (This is undefined behaviour, and almost anything could actually be displayed; the program may also crash, if the `cout` call tries to read memory it doesn't have the required access to).

To correct this, simply add that `nul` (zero, or `'\0'`) character to the end of the string in the `truncate` function. Assuming you don't go beyond the array's bounds, you can use the "left over" value of the loop index, `i`, to access the required element; but, to do so, you will need to declare the `int i` *outside* of the `for` loop's scope:

```cpp
void truncate(char* s1, char* s2, int n)
{
    int i; // Must be declared outside the FOR loop ...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s2[i] = s1[i];
    }
    s2[i] = '\0'; // ... so we can use it here.
}
```

---

Note: Another way (but apparently prohibited by your teacher) would be to set all elements of the `s2` array in `main` to zero, *before* calling your `truncate` function:

```cpp
char s2[10] = ""; // Set ALL elements to zero
```

Some compilers (seemingly including the online one you use) will "implicitly" set the elements of uninitialized local arrays to zero; but ***never rely on this***: it is not part of the C++ Standard and compilers are *not* required to enforce such behaviour.

Comment: `s2[n] = 0;` should work too.

Comment: Note:, as @Fred Larson says, One could also keep the `for` loop as in the original code and just add `s2[n] = 0;` somewhere (anywhere, really) in the `truncate` function. But what I have shown is, IMHO, the more 'idiomatic' C++ or C way of doing such things.