# unexpected undefined characters fread

Tags: c, printf, fread

I am reading a file using a small buffer and printing it. But after every time it after fread and printf some unrecognized characters appear. I do not know why.

I think it has something to do with printf and not fread.
This is the small code:

```
 f = fopen(host_filename2, "r");

char chunks[4];
int size;
do {
    memset(chunks,0,sizeof chunks);
    size = fread(chunks, 1, sizeof chunks, f);
    if (size <= 0) break;
    printf("%s", chunks);
} while (size == sizeof chunks); 

fclose(f);
```

Comment: `printf("%s", chunks);` - `chunks` is not a [null-terminated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037209/what-is-a-null-terminated-string), so `printf` continues to read and print characters until it hit a zero byte, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: For the reason stated in the previous comment, change `printf("%s", chunks);` to `printf("%.*s", size, chunks);`, which will limit the number of characters printed to `size`. See the documentation for [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for further information.

Comment: What you really should do is read one less character and place a null-byte after the call to ```fread```.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe rhat you are reading a text file?

Comment: Instead of `printf`, use `fwrite`.

Answer (score 2):

`printf("%s", chunks);` expect `chunks[]` to be a *string*. Strings have a *null character* at the end and `fread(chunks, 1, sizeof chunks, f)` did not certainly read a `'\0'` and form a string.

**Write what was read**  (Best)

```
// printf("%s", chunks);
fwrite(chunks, 1, size, stdout);
```

**Write what was read up to a `'\0'`**

`"%.*s"` writes a limited amount from a character array, stopping at the `size` or when a `'\0'` is detected.

```
// printf("%s", chunks);
printf("%.*s", size, chunks);
```

**Append your own `'\0'`**

This will perform like `printf("%.*s", size, chunks)`.

```
char chunks[4 + 1];  // One bigger
int size;
do {
    // memset(chunks,0,sizeof chunks - 1);  // Not needed
    size = fread(chunks, 1, sizeof chunks - 1, f);
    if (size <= 0) break;
    chunks[size] = '\0';
    printf("%s", chunks);
} while (size == sizeof chunks - 1);
```

---

**Avoid naked magic numbers**

Use `size_t` for array sizing.

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE 4
char chunks[CHUNK_SIZE];
size_t size;
size_t n = sizeof chunks/sizeof *chunks;
do {
    size = fread(chunks, sizeof *chunks, n, f);
    if (size <= 0) break;
    fwrite(chunks, sizeof *chunks, size, stdout);
} while (size == sizeof chunks);
```